# If-Modified-Since для WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Необходимо корректно настроить If-Modified на wordpress.
Нашел следующий код, с рекомендацией разместить его в хедере или index.php

```
<?php
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 7200).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
$mt = filemtime($file_name);
$mt_str = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s ")."GMT";
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) &&
strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) >= $mt)
{header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
die;
}
header('Last-Modified: '.$mt_str);
echo $text;
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
header("Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch");
?>
```

Код нашел [тут](https://mailbird.kartauspeha.ru/last-modified-if-modified-since.html)

После установки авторизованному пользователю сайт отображается корректно, а в приватном режиме без авторизации вместо страницы показаны иероглифы, будто кодировка сбита.
Пример:
"
��}�G���n`�!E���V�U$��O��j��ْV-�oa�b1I��XUSUl���`_��p�������������+̓\Df�'�f�,Rl�dw7�����������<�x��
"
Причем http://last-modified.com/ru/if-modified-since.html говорит что сайт проходит проверку на корректный If-Modified. Чем может быть вызвана эта проблема и как ее исправляют в подобных случаях?

Comment: Раве Last-Modified заголовка не достаточно? И учитывайте что он должен работать только для custom страниц, постов и записей

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста как это грамотно сделать.